# Hibernate XML Mapping Unidirectional (No Foreign key)

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have been working on a legacy application (Important to state as I can't change the data structure)

I have a lookup table which have ID from two tables, I am trying to get the description from the two tables using unidirectional one to one mapping

Let me also mention that Although the person table has Address_ID and Secondary_Address_id , they are NOT foreign keys to the Address and Secondary_address_table in the database

when I run the query I get the addressDescription and secondaryAddressDescription as null, also when trying to insert into the table Person using getHibernateTemplate.merge(person)

I get the error Hibernate Mismatch Exception for class Address expecting java.lang .long but got integer

Listed below are the Hibernate Mapping Files and the POJO with it

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd" >
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.sample.Person" table="Person">
        <id name="personId" type="java.lang.Integer" column="PERSON_ID">
            <generator class="native" />
        </id>



        <property name="addressId" column="ADDRESS_ID" type="java.lang.Long" />
        <property name="secondaryAddressId" column="SECONDARY_ADDRESS" type="java.lang.Integer" />
        <property name="primary" column="PRIMARY" type="java.lang.String" />

        <one-to-one name="address" class="com.sample.Address" cascade="none" foreign-key="addressId" >

        </one-to-one>

        <one-to-one name="secondaryAddress" class="com.sample.SecondaryAddress" cascade="none" foreign-key="secondaryAddressId">

        </one-to-one>

    </class>

    <query name="Address.getAddressById">
        <![CDATA[
  Select per.personId as personId,per.addressId as addressId,
                       per.secondaryAddressId as secondaryAddressId,, ad.description as addressDescription, sad.description as secondaryAddressDescription
                        from Person per left join per.address ad left join per.secondaryAddress sad  where
                         per.personId=:personId
   ]]>
    </query>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

Hibernate Mapping for Address

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd" >
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.Address" table="ADDRESS">
        <id name="addressId" type="java.lang.Long" column="ADDRESS_ID">
            <generator class="native" />
        </id>

        <property name="description" column="DESCRIPTION" type="java.lang.String" not-null="true"/>

    </class>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

Hibernate Mapping for SecondaryAddress

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd" >
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.SecondaryAddress" table="SECONDARY_ADDRESS">
        <id name="secondaryAddressId" type="java.lang.Integer" column="SECONDARY_ADDRESS_ID">
            <generator class="native" />
        </id>

        <property name="description" column="DESCRIPTION" type="java.lang.String" not-null="true"/>

    </class>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

POJO for Person (Not pasting the getter/setters to have less code here)

```
public class Person implements Serializable {

    /**
     *
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1186272503323568780L;



    private Integer personId;
    private Long addressId;
    private Integer secondaryAddressId;
    private String addressDescription;
    private String secondaryAddressDescription;
    private Integer address;
    private String secondaryAddress;

  }
```

Comment: If you're getting `expecting java.lang .long but got integer` start by changing your ID type from Integer to Long on your entities

Comment: there is only one filed Address_ID defined as Bigint in the table and i have that defined as long in my entities as well as POJO